# Find CiviCRM version programmatically?

Tags: extension, developer

Within a CiviCRM extension, what's the best way to determine the current CiviCRM version in versions 4.6.x and above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agree with Chris that `System.get` is a great API for inspecting the system -- with a trade-off of breadth vs speed.

If you need something more performant, use `CRM_Utils_System::version()`, e.g.

```
$ cv ev 'return CRM_Utils_System::version();'
"4.7.16"
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd use `System.get` API call. ([source](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/System.php#L222))

In the return values, there's a value for `version` which corresponds to the value in `civicrm-version.php`

```
$ cv api System.get name=version
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "id": 0,
    "values": [
        {
            "version": "4.6.20.0",
            "uf": "Drupal",
            "php": {
            // lots more info ...
```

Only worry about this might be how heavy that API call is - since I see data there from OS etc, it might not be suitable for calling frequently if rebuilding the data each time. There seems to be a bit of overhead to this API call (~0.07s per call in a randomly picked test environment), so for frequent use you'd want something lighter.